# Do I use a title in the mention "joint with [...]" when mentioning my advisor or a coworker?

Tags: titles

I'm making presentation slides, which will be on the work of my Ph.D. advisor (Dr. X, full professor), a postdoc. (Dr. Y, the job title is visiting assistant professor) and myself. I'm trying to find a way to most accurately/politely address them.

Should I address them using the same generic title, such as

> "Joint work with Professors X and Y"
>
> "Joint work with Dr. X and Dr. Y"

or should I use different titles?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, you're not addressing them (talking _to_ them) but referring to them (talking _about_ them).

Comment: If you really want to include that sort of info, adding *, PhD* would be my first choice.

Comment: @AzorAhai This is not good advice. This would certainly be a *faux pas*. Nobody does it, so if OP does it, it will stand out, and not in a good way. Apart from conferences geared towards young mathematicians, the majority of people in the audience will have a PhD if not more. Emphasizing it will be just weird. If someone asks "Should I shoot myself in the foot?", I don't think "If you really want to do it, shoot a toe, it will a lesser loss" is a good thing to reply.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I'm not familiar with math, which is why I left a comment. In my field, about 65% of people I work with hold a PhD, and 40% an MD. Having that info on the title slide could give you information on how the researchers approached the problem. I wouldn't say it's *required*, but that may be why it's acceptable to me to list credentials whereas in math, it would be strange.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my experience (math), I have never seen a title used on such an occasion. It's always "joint with Jane Doe and John Doe", i.e. the full name without any title. Even if it's a student jointly working with a professor.

Think about it: in a bibliography you never use any title. The goal of the mention "joint with" is the same as in a bibliography: give credit where credit is due, and let people look up who did the work. A title is unnecessary for that.

Answer (score 7):

Just ask them - they will know exactly what is relevant for that presentation...